# Console Application to retrieve Domain Shared Contacts (Google Apps Admin SDK)

Tags: c#, google-admin-sdk

I need to write a console application to retrieve domain shared contacts (eventually update, add or delete them, too).

What I found so far is "[Google Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/)" should do just that, but I am a bit clueless as where to start.

I don't know how to access this API in .NET and I haven't found any examples of such a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to come up with an application that sends http requests to the API, however their documentation is terrible as it lacks complete description of how exactly the requests should look like and I had to experiment a bit.

Comment: Tell me about it. I'm a problem where I can create emails but not names. Do you happen to have any examples you'd be willing to share?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see in the documentation, Domain Shared Contacts API is not currently included in the list of [Supported Google APIs for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/) .

You may, however, check in [Release Notes for the Google API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/release_notes) for announcement or updates regarding this API.

If the time comes that Domain Shared Contacts API becomes supported, you may use the following references to get started:

- [Easily access Google APIs from .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/)
- [GitHub post - google-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client)
- [GitHub post - google-api-dotnet-client-samples](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples)